# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in acorn while running -npm run css:watch

Tags: javascript, php, tailwind-css, acorn

Rebuilding...
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (16:4)
at pp$4.raise (/Users/ajeshofficial/Local Sites/nintriva/app/public/wp-content/themes/nintriva/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2927:15)
at pp.unexpected (/Users/ajeshofficial/Local Sites/nintriva/app/public/wp-content/themes/nintriva/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:698:10)
at pp.expect (/Users/ajeshofficial/Local Sites/nintriva/app/public/wp-content/themes/nintriva/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:692:28)
at pp$3.parseExprList (/Users/ajeshofficial/Local Sites/nintriva/app/public/wp-content/themes/nintriva/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2818:14)
at pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/ajeshofficial/Local Sites/nintriva/app/public/wp-content/themes/nintriva/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2298:28)
at _class.parseExprAtom (/Users/ajeshofficial/Local Sites/nintriva/app/public/wp-content/themes/nintriva/node_modules/acorn-node/lib/dynamic-import/index.js:77:117)
at pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/ajeshofficial/Local Sites/nintriva/app/public/wp-content/themes/nintriva/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2129:21)
at pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/ajeshofficial/Local Sites/nintriva/app/public/wp-content/themes/nintriva/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2106:19)
at _class.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/ajeshofficial/Local Sites/nintriva/app/public/wp-content/themes/nintriva/node_modules/acorn-node/lib/private-class-elements/index.js:122:54)
at pp$3.parseExprOps (/Users/ajeshofficial/Local Sites/nintriva/app/public/wp-content/themes/nintriva/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2041:21) {
pos: 503,
loc: Position { line: 16, column: 4 },
raisedAt: 533
}

**npm run css:watch
returns this error message**

**this is my package.json**
{
"name": "suitejar",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"css:watch": "npx tailwindcss -i ./css/main.css -o ./css/flutter-page.css --watch",
"css:build": "npx tailwindcss -i ./css/main.css -o ./css/flutter-page.css --minify"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9"
},
"dependencies": {
"@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2"
}
}